# Nginx - 301 redirect for pages with specific GET param to the same page without get params

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have

- many pages which were indexed by search engines with crappy GET-parameter like `_escaped_fragment_` (for more info about escaped fragments see more [Yandex man page](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.html?lang=en))
- `nginx` as reverse proxy in front of many different frontend apps

So I need to get 301 redirect only for all these pages with some GET-parameter to the same pages but without any get parameters. For example

```
example.com/some/long/path?_escaped_fragment_=
```

should be 301-redirected to

```
example.com/some/long/path
```

I can do it by adding this logic to each frontend app or I can do it at nginx configuration. I prefer to use second variant.

**Potential solution** can include

- using [http rewrite module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)
- using [if in rewrite](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) to check GET-params
- using [map module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) to define request uri path without args from [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my initial issue in such manner

- add below code to my `http context` to define request uri path without args from [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) (here we use [map module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map))

  ```
  map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
      "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$"  $path;
  }
  ```
- add below code to my `server context` to make `301 redirect` from pages with `_escaped_fragment_` in GET parameters to the same pages without any GET parameters (here we use [rewrite module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite))

  ```
  if ($args ~*  "_escaped_fragment_") {
      rewrite ^ $scheme://$host$request_uri_path? permanent;
  }
  ```

And this works for me.